# Export assigned Labels to a task in planner in office 365

Tags: excel, label, office365, power-automate, microsoft-planner

While there are multiple solutions available online to export plan to an excel, some of the export options are still in uncharted area. For e.g. i have edited few of the existing Labels to a customized name and not every label is assigned to every task under a plan. Is there any way i can export the assigned labels taskwise ?

I tried to find options in power automate but in vain. Let me know your thoughts . Thanks !

For e.g. [image]

Here you can see task xyz has multiple Labels like Dev, Testing and Sample. If i would like to export them too into an excel sheet along with other details of the task, what would be the best way ?

Comment: This may sound like a stupid questions but can you give us an example of what you mean by "labels".  Maybe show a screenshot or something.

Comment: @Skin - As suggested I have updated the question with screenshot and example. Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

Names of the labels are in the Plan Details entity, [CategoryDescriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/plannercategorydescriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0) property. You can read this once per plan to get all the names, then appliedCategories field on each task will indicate which labels are applied to the specific task. You can use the name of the property in the appliedCategories field to directly look up the value in the name from the plan.

You could also [export a plan to excel from Planner directly](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-a-plan-to-excel-4d850c6e-e548-4aab-83b4-b62b68662d2a), without writing code (which includes labels as well), in case you don't need an automated solution.

Answer (score -1):

The tags do exist in each planned task but you're going to hate this, they come through in the `appliedCategories` object and they're represented by the order of the category itself.

```
"appliedCategories": {
    "category2": true,
    "category3": true,
    "category4": true,
    "category11": true
}
```

You can rename them all you like but those names aren't pulled through in the response.

You'll need to manage the names in your own mapping table or the like to get what you want.

To see it working, select labels in random positions and then run the `List my tasks` action and you'll see them there.

[image: Labels]